# Blackberry HttpConnection failure on device

Tags: http, blackberry, get, connection, device

I'm after some BlackBerry suggestions again. I'm developing a REST based app using the standard BB code that appends to the URI connection string (I'll post if you like but don't want to take up space here as I suspect that those of you that know about this know exactly what I mean).

The code works fine in the emulator in MDS mode and is good on the phone too with straight WiFi.

Now, the problem is when I come to use 3G on an actual phone. At that point it fails. Is this some kind of transcoding problem?

I'm using a raw HttpConnection.

An HTTP POST works (with body info) but the GET (which uses a cookie for auth purposes as a header requestproperty) fails.

The failure is only with header (GET) based info on non WiFi connections on the mobile device.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

```
public static String httpGet(Hashtable params, String uriIn) {

        String result = null;

        LoginDetails loginDetails = LoginDetails.getInstance();

        HttpConnection _connection;

        String uri = uriIn + "?api_key=" + loginDetails.getApi_key();

        Enumeration e = params.keys();

        // iterate through Hashtable keys Enumeration
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) (e.nextElement());
            String value = (String) params.get(key);

            uri += "&" + key + "=" + value;

        }

        uri = uri + HelperMethods.getConnectionString();

        try {

            _connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(uri);

            _connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            _connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

            _connection.setRequestProperty("x-rim-authentication-passthrough",
                    "true");

            _connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", loginDetails.getCookie());

            _connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            String charset = "UTF-8";

            _connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            _connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);

            OutputStream _outputStream = _connection.openOutputStream();

            int rc = _connection.getResponseCode();

            InputStream _inputStream = _connection.openInputStream();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int ch;
            while ((ch = _inputStream.read()) != -1) {

                bytestream.write(ch);

            }

            result = new String(bytestream.toByteArray());

            bytestream.close();


            {

                if (_outputStream != null)
                    try {
                        _outputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                    }
                if (_connection != null)
                    try {
                        _connection.close();
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                    }

            }

        } catch (IOException e3) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;

    }
```

And this uses:

```
public synchronized static String getConnectionString() {

        String connectionString = null;

        // Simulator behaviour is controlled by the USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR
        // variable.
        if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {

            connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
        }

        // Wifi is the preferred transmission method
        else if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {

            connectionString = ";interface=wifi";
        }

        // Is the carrier network the only way to connect?
        else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {

            String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();

            if (carrierUid == null) {
                // Has carrier coverage, but not BIBS. So use the carrier's TCP
                // network

                connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
            } else {
                // otherwise, use the Uid to construct a valid carrier BIBS
                // request

                connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
            }
        }

        // Check for an MDS connection instead (BlackBerry Enterprise Server)
        else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {

            connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
        }

        // If there is no connection available abort to avoid hassling the user
        // unnecssarily.
        else if (CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE) {
            connectionString = "none";

        }

        // In theory, all bases are covered by now so this shouldn't be reachable.But hey, just in case ...
        else {

            connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
        }



        return connectionString;
    }

    /**
     * Looks through the phone's service book for a carrier provided BIBS
     * network
     * 
     * @return The uid used to connect to that network.
     */
    private synchronized static String getCarrierBIBSUid() {
        ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
        int currentRecord;

        for (currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++) {
            if (records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp")) {
                if (records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase()
                        .indexOf("bibs") >= 0) {
                    return records[currentRecord].getUid();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What kind of failure are you actually getting?  Please show the actual error.  Also, why are you setting the request `Content-Type` multiple times to different values before sending the request?  You cannot send any body data in a `GET` request, so it does not make sense to even set the `Content-Type` at all, since there is no content.  The charset of the URL is dictated by the server, not the HTTP headers.

Comment: Things are set multiple times for testing. None actually work on the device.

Comment: Why would this work on WiFi on the device and not on other services?

Comment: And the same applies now I've removed the Content-Type etc. That makes no difference whatsoever. The POST request works via all means but the GET above doesn't unless WiFi is used on the device.

Comment: You still have not said what the actual problem is. Just saying it doesn't work is not helpful information. **WHAT** is not working correctly? **WHAT** is failing exactly? On which line? Is there an exception being thrown? Is there an error message being reported?

Comment: No exception is being thrown, the server complains (in the response) that 'invalid characters' are being parsed via a REST response. Now why would that be? It works on WiFi - you've seen the standard code I use to append to the uri.

Comment: That suggests to me that something is VERY different about how BB phones deal with differing comms types.

Comment: If the REST server is receiving the request and sending a response back, then the problem is not in the connection.  A `GET` request passes data via the URL, whereas a `POST` request passes data in the post body instead.  I don't see you percent-encoding any characters that are unsafe in a URL, for instance.

Comment: Ah you have a good point - I'll try that later when I get back from work and report back. Thanks for the help so far. I still don't see why it Would work with WiFi an not the other 2 routes though.

Comment: And a simple %20 replace worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed - see above.

It turns out that there were spaces in the uri's.

Quite why this worked over WiFi & not 3G etc. is still puzzling.